# I care not (for these things) vs. I don't care

Tags: grammar, word-order, negation, subject-verb-inversion

Is the expression "I care not" grammatically correct?

Do ***I care not*** and ***I don't care***  have the same meaning?

Comment: A friendly point of advice: if you provide a bit of background or context for your question you will get a better response.

Answer (score 3):

You will never hear *I care not* in casual conversation in the modern context.  It is grammatically correct, but it would be likely perceived as affected, old-fashioned or a deliberate attempt to sound poetic.